# Blank page after installation and admin 404

Tags: magento2, nginx, php-7, centos

I have installed Magento 2 on a CentOS 7 server with PHP 7.0.9 and NGINX 1.11.3 using the command line.
After running the installation, when we try to load the home page we get nothing but a blank page.
I do see a 500 error in the browser console, but i cant find anything in the PHP or NGINX logs.
On top of this, when I try to go to the admin, I am getting a 404 error.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You should check your php.ini configuration if your getting a 500 with no logs at all, it is almost certain that your php error logging has been turned off.

Comment: In the php.ini file, error_reporting is set to "E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT".

Answer (score 1):

In your php.ini settings, add/amend the below configuration. That should show you an error that points you in the right direction next time you try to load the page:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me determine that the home page front end was not loading because of permissions issues on the var folder (<Magento site root>/var) and the php sessions folder (/var/lib/php/session).. I am still trying to troubleshoot the 404 error for the admin back end though.

Comment: Cool. Please upvote answer if you found it useful. Don't forget to turn display_errors off after as it is deemed a security issue in a production environment.

Comment: Thank you, would you happen to have any ideas for the 404 error on the admin back end?

Comment: It's hard to say if you aren't getting any php error reports that help when trying to load Admin. Sounds silly, but when I'm messing with a Magento Development Environment, I will often load the site in Incognito mode as I've been caught out by cookies before. Other than that, I can only suggest that you will find a rough idea of the problem in var/system.log or var/exception.log